# Image preprocessing digits in captcha

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm training a model to read a specific type of captcha image.
This is what the images look like:

[image: Example captcha]

They all have exactly 4 digits, which may or may not overlap slightly, and have random pastel colors. [This url](https://www.tjrs.jus.br/site_php/consulta/human_check/humancheck_showcode.php?) will generate a new random captcha on each refresh.

Before doing any OCR, I'm trying to clean up the image as best as I can.
Here's my best solution so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def blob_filter(input, min_size):
  nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(input, connectivity = 8)
  sizes = stats[1:, -1];
  nb_components = nb_components - 1
  filtered = np.zeros((output.shape))
  for i in range(0, nb_components):
      if sizes[i] >= min_size:
          filtered[output == i + 1] = 255
  
  return filtered

def read_and_preprocess(image_path):
  original = cv2.imread(image_path)
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  _, _, v = cv2.split(hsv)
  blurred = cv2.blur(v, (2,2))
  _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  filtered = blob_filter(thresh, 80)
  return np.asarray(filtered)

im_path = "yl5ux.jpg"
example = read_and_preprocess(im_path)
plt.imshow(example, cmap='gray')
```

I noticed that the digits are most visible in the V channel in HSV space, so I basically just blur and threshold this channel, then remove most of the blob artefacts that are left. This produces something like this:

[image]

This result is generally satisfactory but the edges are still very noisy and the thresholds some times cut off parts of some digits.

I'm wondering if anybody can suggest a different approach or additional steps to improve the legibility of these digits.

I've tried some morphological operations, low-pass filtering in frequency domain and a low-variance filter, but none of them produced better or robust results for all images.

[This link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JxytMhm6_cWKQU7JO_7v8RuEGAZ40j1f/view?usp=sharing) provides 2000 sample captchas with labels for download, for anybody interested in experimenting.

Comment: *don't* "clean up" the picture. let the network learn that. preprocessing only removes information from the data.

Comment: using only value from hsv doesn't seem very robust to me, maybe you can use hue and saturation values, this is just a thought: for several hue ranges which have at least S saturation do either contour analysis or edges with connected components. each hue range you get a binary mask which you or together.